# File write error while uploading via FileZilla

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, sftp, root, ftp

I have a user xyz which is able to create files in a directory, but when I try to write something on the newly created file, it fails. The file has proper read-write permissions to the owner i.e. xyz. When I try to edit the same file via root, it succeeds.

So, what can be the issue? Everything was working perfectly few days back, where I was under a proxy server.

Also, even on giving correct username and password to my phpMyAdmin, it logs in but redirects again to my login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to all of these was lack of space on my computer. I increased the space and all the issues flew here. Posting here in case anyone else goes through similar situation.